# Насколько правильно составлен select и как через Join сделать?

Tags: mysql, sql

Таблица и дамп:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ftpuploadermon` (
  `date` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event` text,
  `region` text,
  `host` text,
  `type` text,
  `info` text,
  `status` text,
  `timestamp` timestamp(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `ftpuploadermon` (`date`, `event`, `region`, `host`, `type`, `info`, `status`, `timestamp`) VALUES
('2016-10-14 17:01:26.974', 'WARN ', 'SZ', 'SIU02', '[main]', 'Started, locked port 6696', '0', '2016-10-14 16:19:39.241'),
('2016-10-14 16:58:23.946', 'WARN ', 'SZ', 'SIU02', '[main]', 'Stop signal !', '1', '2016-10-14 16:17:01.335'),
('2016-10-14 16:58:23.946', 'WARN ', 'POV', 'SIU02', '[main]', 'Stop signal !', '1', '2016-10-14 16:17:39.851');
```

Выбираю следующим select из нее:

```
SELECT a.date,a.region,a.host,a.type,a.info,a.status 
FROM ftpuploadermon a, 
( SELECT info,type,timestamp, max(date) as time FROM ftpuploadermon GROUP BY type ) b 
WHERE a.type = b.type AND a.date = b.time AND a.status <> '0' 
ORDER BY a.`date` DESC
```

Смысл select в том, чтобы выбрать максимальное по времени значение с группировкой по `type`.
Но результат выборки не совсем тот, который нужен.

Т.е он выдает пустой результат выборки. А должен был выбрать максимальное значение по условию для которого status <> 0
Т.е должен быть результат :

```
('2016-10-14 16:58:23.946', 'WARN ', 'POV', 'SIU02', '[main]', 'Stop signal !', '1', '2016-10-14 16:17:39.851');
```

Вообще наверно лучше это все как-то через JOIN сделать , но я пока не соображу как.

Comment: Перенесите условие status<>0 во внутренний запрос. А то вы сначала выбираете максимальное по времени событие (в 17:01), а потом уже его статус проверяете, а у него статус как раз 0. А вообще вы и так join делаете, потому как оператор запятая (`,`) практически синоним join

Comment: Перенес. В результате получаю две строки ,  у одной из которых время раньше, че у второй, которая в выборку не попала.


SELECT a.date,a.region,a.host,a.type,a.info,a.status FROM ftpuploadermon a, ( SELECT info,type,t_stamp, max(date) as time FROM ftpuploadermon WHERE status <> '0' GROUP BY type ) b WHERE a.type = b.type AND a.date = b.time ORDER BY a.`date` DESC

Comment: Логично .... у вас поле `date` у двух записей абсолютно одинаковое. А поле timestamp разное. определитесь по каким полям вы будете брать уникальную нужную запись. Хотя можете поле status проверять и внутри и снаружи. Я же не знаю логики ваших данных, сами решайте

Comment: Да верно. Моя ошибка в данном случае. Не заметил, что время одинаковое.

Answer (score 0):

c join

```
SELECT a.date,a.region,a.host,a.type,a.info,a.status 
FROM ftpuploadermon a
   inner join ( SELECT info,type,timestamp, max(date) as time 
                FROM ftpuploadermon 
                where a.status <> '0'
                GROUP BY  info,type,timestamp
              ) b  on a.type = b.type AND a.date = b.time
ORDER BY a.`date` DESC
```

Comment: Такая конструкция выдает результат где status=1 для всех значений. Т.е на данном примере результат должен быть один:

Comment: Вот такой результат должен быть только ('2016-10-14 16:58:23.946', 'WARN ', 'POV', 'SIU02', '[main]', 'Stop signal !', '1', '2016-10-14 16:17:39.851');

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.date,a.region,a.host,a.type,a.info,a.status
FROM ftpuploadermon a, ( SELECT info,type, max(date) as time
                         FROM ftpuploadermon
                         WHERE status <> '0'
                         GROUP BY type ) b
WHERE a.type = b.type AND a.date = b.time
ORDER BY a.date DESC
```